# Ставится ли запятая перед "и всё такое"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Ну, так как я шериф(,) и всё такое, я подумал, что...
>
> Раз уж вы всё равно решили пойти в штаб(,) и всё такое, то...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не ставится.

1. > Ну, так как я шериф и всё такое, я подумал, что...

Здесь возможны два взгляда: 1) *шериф* и *все такое* – однородные члены, 2) *я шериф* и *все такое* – разные грамматические основы, соединенные союзом *и*, но не разделенные запятой, т. к. имеется общий подчинительный союз *так как*.

2. > Раз уж вы всё равно решили пойти в штаб и всё такое, то...

Здесь опять общий подчинительный союз *раз*, так что запятая в любом случае не ставится.

Comment: @ Aer♦, союз в сложном предложении не выступает общим элементом. В нашем случае - это однородные придаточные предложения, поэтому запятая не ставится.

Comment: @Серж то есть, по-вашему, союз _так как_ __не относится__ к какому-то из придаточных?

Comment: Я говорю о том, что это однородные придаточные.

Comment: @Серж а я говорю о том, что союз _так как_ общий для обоих придаточных, т. е. относится к каждому из них в равной степени.

Comment: Да, тогда это другое дело. Просто из вашей формулировки получается, что ССП, в котором союз является общим элементом.